# How to represent a Python-like dictionary in C

Tags: c, dictionary

In Python it's easy:

```
x = {}
x['USD'] = "Dollars"
x['CLP'] = "Pesos"
```

or

```
y = {'lat': 23.678900, 'lng': 121.451928, 'name': "Sin City"}
```

I think most of these kinds of problems have been solved, so where can I get information about dictionaries in C? I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

How do I implement a dictionary in C?

Comment: You may wish to read up about Hash Tables: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table it's a pretty important data structure, and understanding how they work, as well as the benefits (and cons) of using one is really important and will give you a better understanding to the hows and whys of python dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

They are called hash tables or hash maps.

There are lots of std ones for C++.

See [Simple hash functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409466/simple-hash-functions)

Answer (score 2):

glibc provides hcreate, hsearch, and hdestroy.

Answer (score 1):

All your questions are answered [here](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.16/16.10/AssociativeArrays/index.html).

The idea: use a hash function avoiding collisions to use them as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables are fine. If you want to stick to standard C library functions, there's also [bsearch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/) which is good for constant lookup dictionaries, or dynamic dictionaries in conjunction with [qsort](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/stdlib.h/qsort.php).