# C map data structure

Tags: c, hashmap

I want to implement a key value pair data structure in C. Any idea?

Comment: What are you mapping to what? What functions do you need?

Comment: int to int mapping. EX
1 -> 2
3 -> 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c

Answer (score 13):

> [This](http://pokristensson.com/strmap.html) is a simple hash table
>   implementation in ANSI C. It supports
>   the rudimentary functions generally
>   expected of a hash table:

- Inserting and retrieving key-value associations
- Querying the existence of a key
- Returning the total number of key-value associations
- Enumerating over all key-value associations

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, to be a  bit pedantic, that is not ANSI C since it defines functions whose names start with "str". You can't do that, the entire space of global functions names that start with "str" is reserved.

Comment: I don't like it, because it doesn't specify th esource code of the functions, and it does not seem to expand or shrink. It just has a fixed number of items.

Answer (score 10):

If your key and value part are same data type then you can use a 2-D array with 2 column where first column will be your key and second will be data.
IT will behave as map but time complexity will diff.
Time complexity :
search  -  O(n)
Insert -
want to maintain unique key then O(n)
else
    O(1).

```
int map[N][2];
```

if you want to have key-value pair different type then you can use list structure.

```
struct node
{
int key;  //key part
string value;  // value part
struct node *next;
};
```

Time complexity :
search  -  O(n)
Insert -
want to maintain unique key then O(n)
else
    O(1).

Comment: upvote for the timecomplexity hint.

Answer (score 1):

Typical map functions are also supported by the hashmap implementation in [libmba](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/dl/docs/ref/hashmap.html).

I found about it a while ago, though I haven't used it. You can also check the library project [homepage](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/).

I hope it might be prove useful to someone.