# Does C have hash/dictionary data structure?

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm learning C now coming from knowing perl and a bit python. I did a quick search and found there is no explicit hash/dictionary as in perl/python and I saw people were saying you need a function to look up a hash table. So the fact is C doesn't provide an inherent hash structure and you have to write some function to be able to use hash in C?

Comment: Yes, C standard library does not provide any such data structure but You might use some non standard library which provides the functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hashtable as part of Standard C Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118539/hashtable-as-part-of-standard-c-library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, the only data structure that C has are arrays, structs (which is kind of like a map, but the keys must be known at compile time) and unions. Everything else must be coded manually or provided by a library.

Answer (score 7):

Ignore all the above misleading answers, C does have a standard library for
this, long before all those fancy languages existed. The basic version only
does one table, the GNU version as many as you want.

```
#include <search.h>

int hcreate(size_t nel);

ENTRY *hsearch(ENTRY item, ACTION action);

void hdestroy(void);

#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <search.h>

int hcreate_r(size_t nel, struct hsearch_data *htab);

int hsearch_r(ENTRY item, ACTION action, ENTRY **retval, struct hsearch_data *htab);

void hdestroy_r(struct hsearch_data *htab);
```

checkout the:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hcreate.html

Answer (score 4):

It's not part of standard C libraries.  Use a library such as Glib.

Comment: I think Oswald gave a better answer but you gave the OP a solution if they want that type of functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540/good-stl-like-library-for-c

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at a very nice library [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.36/):

> GLib is a general-purpose utility library, which provides many useful
>   data types, macros, type conversions, string utilities, file
>   utilities, a mainloop abstraction, and so on. It works on many
>   UNIX-like platforms, as well as Windows and OS X. GLib is released
>   under the GNU Library General Public License (GNU LGPL).

There are many OpenSource projects that use this library: GNOME, Wireshark and many more.
Glib includes implementations of a number of useful data structures, such as:

- Hash table (GHashTable)
- Doubly-Linked List (GList)
- Queue (QQueue)
- Dataset
- etc