# How to multiprocess in a for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

```
import string
import hashlib
import itertools

hash_list = [hash1,hash2,hash3,...]
allchar = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

def crack(msg):
    temp = hashlib.md5(msg.encode('utf-8)).hexdigest()
    for hashvalue in hash_list:
        if temp == hashvalue:
            print(msg)
            hash_list.remove(hashvalue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 1
    while len(hash_list) > 0:
        for result in itertools.product(allchar, repeat = n):
            msg = ''.join(result)
            crack(msg)
        n += 1
```

I wrote this program for cracking hashes. How can I utilize multiprocessing in this program? I tried to store all the product of the itertool in a list for mapping, but that list becomes too big. Is there a memory-efficient way to multiprocess this program? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried generating a subset of the `itertools.product` and then pass each subset to a worker:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def crack(alist):
    ...
    return result

def gather(result):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    g = itertools.product(allchar, repeat = n)

    while True:
        try:
            ss = [next(g) for _ in _ in range(10000)]
            pool.apply_async(crack, ss, gather)
        except StopIteration:
            pool.apply_async(crack, ss, gather)
            break
```

EDIT per @juanpa.arrivillaga and modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079667/2718295

Set up some queues and populate it in the master process. The worker is responsible for consuming passwords:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool, Lock

def crack(q, q2, lock):
    while True:
        temp = q.get()
        if temp is None:
            break

        hash_list = q2.get()
        if not hash_list:
            # empty set
            break

        h = hashlib.md5(temp.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

        for hashvalue in hash_list:
            if h == hashvalue:
                hash_list = hash_list.discard(hashvalue)
                with lock:
                    print(''.join(temp))
                    # resynchronize the hashlist
                    hash_list2 = q2.get()
                    q2.put(hash_list & hash_list2 )     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NCORE = 4
    q = Queue(maxsize=NCORE)
    q2 = Queue(maxsize=NCORE)
    lock = Lock()

    hash_list = set([hash1,hash2,hash3,...])
    allchar = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

    pool = Pool(NCORE, initializer=crack, initargs=(q,q2,lock))
    q2.put(hash_list)
    for result in itertools.product(allchar, repeat = n):
        q.put(result)

    for _ in range(NCORE):
        q.put(None)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: use `itertools.islice` instead of `[next(g) ....]` But anyway, this will still end up using about the same amount of memory once all the workers are initialized (actually, *more* because of process overhead).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`.

```
from concurrent import futures
from multiprocess import Manager

hash_list = Manager().list([hash1, hash2, hash3, ...])

def crack(msg):
    temp = hashlib.md5(msg.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
    for hashvalue in hash_list:
        if temp == hashvalue:
            print(msg)
            hash_list.remove(hashvalue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1
    while hash_list;
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(crak, [''.join(result) for result in itertools.product(allchar, repeat = n)])
        n += 1
```