# Multiprocessing to brute force missing chars in b64-encoded data using generators - possible/how to?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, python-multiprocessing

Working with processing  data that I receive as b64-encoded strings. For some reason I received  data the other day where a set of the b64-encoded strings had four white space chars in them, making the decoded output incorrect. I made a small python script to brute force the missing characters that did the job, but I wanted to see if I can improve the speed by multiprocessing.
I'm not that familiar with using generators so it seems like this is throwing me off in the process of making it work together with multiprocessing.

Following sample code isn't the exact code I'm working with, but similar enough.

```python
import base64
from maskprocessor import maskprocessor as maskproc
from tqdm import tqdm
import string
import multiprocessing as mp

NCORE = 8
KEY = b"some decryption key"
printable_chars = set(bytes(string.printable, 'ascii'))

def printable(data):
    return True if all(char in printable_chars for char in data) else False

def decrypt(cipher):
    try:
        plain = base64.b64decode(cipher) #someDecryptAlgo(KEY, base64.b64decode(cipher))
        return plain
    except:
        return None

def slow_generator(ciphers):
    def gen_to_queue(input_q, ciphers):
        for cipher in ciphers:
            input_q.put(cipher)
        for _ in range(NCORE):
            input_q.put((None,None))

    def process(input_q, output_q):
        while True:
            cipher = input_q.get()
            if cipher is None:
                output_q.put(None)
                break
            output_q.put((cipher, decrypt(cipher)))

    input_q = mp.Queue(maxsize=NCORE * 2)
    output_q = mp.Queue(maxsize=NCORE * 2)

    gen_pool = mp.Pool(1, initializer=gen_to_queue, initargs=(input_q, ciphers))
    pool = mp.Pool(NCORE, initializer=process, initargs=(input_q, output_q))

    finished_workers = 0
    while True:
        cipher, plain = output_q.get()
        if plain is None:
            finished_workers += 1
            if finished_workers == NCORE:
                break
        else:
            yield cipher, plain

if __name__ == "__main__":
    actual_msg = "All your base are belong to us"
    actual_data_b64 = b'QWxsIHlvdXIgYmFzZSBhcmUgYmVsb25nIHRvIHVz' # "All your base are belong to us
    received_data_b64 = b'QWxsI lvdXIgY FzZSBhcmUg mVsb25n HRvIHVz'
    charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+/"
    n_ws = received_data_b64.decode('utf-8').count(' ')
    g = maskproc(received_data_b64.decode('utf-8').replace(' ', '?1'), custom_charset1=charset)
    output = slow_generator(g)
    for cipher, plain in zip(x[0], x[1]):
        if printable(plain):
            if plain.decode('utf-8') == actual_msg:
                print(f"Found correct cipher: {cipher}")
                print(f"Secret message: {plain}")
                break
```

The decoded b64 data is then decrypted using a static key, so the function for checking if I've found the correct bytes is obviously more complex than in the sample above, but I think the sample represents the same problem I got, making the generator work with multiprocessing. There is no reading/writing files involved.

I'd like to avoid creating a list of all the candidates that the `maskproc` generator creates but so far I haven't been able to make `multiprocessing` work without doing this, and thus I wonder if anyone got some pointers for how to do this?

Edit: Say I want to run `N` (4/8/16/etc) processes in parallel, could it be an idea to make a list of length `N` with candidates that is then processed and in this way avoid having to make a list of length 64^4?

Edit2: Changed code to the one adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832140/853898

Edit3: Think I managed to get it working. Now to only find a way to implement a tqdm progress bar, if possible.

```
import base64
from maskprocessor import maskprocessor as maskproc
from tqdm import tqdm
import string
import multiprocessing as mp

NCORE = 8
KEY = b"some decryption key"
printable_chars = set(bytes(string.printable, 'ascii'))

def printable(data):
    return True if all(char in printable_chars for char in data) else False

def decrypt(cipher):
    try:
        plain = base64.b64decode(cipher) #someDecryptAlgo(KEY, base64.b64decode(cipher))
        return plain
    except:
        return None

def slow_generator(ciphers):
    def gen_to_queue(input_q, ciphers):
        for cipher in ciphers:
            input_q.put(cipher)
        for _ in range(NCORE):
            input_q.put(None)

    def process(input_q, output_q):
        while True:
            cipher = input_q.get()
            if cipher is None:
                output_q.put((None, None))
                break
            output_q.put((cipher, decrypt(cipher)))

    input_q = mp.Queue(maxsize=NCORE * 2)
    output_q = mp.Queue(maxsize=NCORE * 2)

    gen_pool = mp.Pool(1, initializer=gen_to_queue, initargs=(input_q, ciphers))
    pool = mp.Pool(NCORE, initializer=process, initargs=(input_q, output_q))

    finished_workers = 0
    while True:
        cipher, plain = output_q.get()
        if plain is None:
            finished_workers += 1
            if finished_workers == NCORE:
                break
        else:
            yield cipher, plain

if __name__ == "__main__":
    actual_msg = "All your base are belong to us"
    actual_data_b64 = b'QWxsIHlvdXIgYmFzZSBhcmUgYmVsb25nIHRvIHVz' # "All your base are belong to us
    received_data_b64 = b'QWxsI lvdXIgY FzZSBhcmUg mVsb25n HRvIHVz'
    #charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+/"
    charset = "HmYI"
    n_ws = received_data_b64.decode('utf-8').count(' ')
    g = maskproc(received_data_b64.decode('utf-8').replace(' ', '?1'), custom_charset1=charset)
    output = slow_generator(g)
    for cipher, plain in output:
        if printable(plain):
            if plain.decode('utf-8') == actual_msg:
                print(f"Found correct cipher: {cipher}")
                print(f"Secret message: {plain}")
                break
```

Comment: Have you found this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078980/python-multiprocessing-with-generator

There is quite a few questions and answers to multiprocessing and generator on SO.

Comment: @MarekSchwarz I have tried to adopt it to the code by Astariul (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832140/853898) but it's not working and I'm quite sure it's something really stupid that I'm not seeing here. I updated the code in the original post to the one I tried to adopt to the suggestions in the thread. If anyone can point out whatever idiot mistake I'm doing I'd be happy, really annoying.

Comment: @MarekSchwarz Got it working now, at least it seems like it when I run it. Now it remains to stop as soon as the correct cipher is found + maybe try to add a tqdm progress bar as well.