# Simple way to parallelize embarrassingly parallelizable generator

Tags: python, parallel-processing, generator

I have a generator (or, a list of generators).  Let's call them `gens`

Each generator in `gens` is a complicated function that returns the next value of a complicated procedure.  Fortunately, they are all independent of one another.

I want to call `gen.__next__()` for each element `gen` in `gens`, and return the resulting values in a list.  However, multiprocessing is unhappy with pickling generators.

Is there a fast, simple way to do this in Python?  I would like it such that `gens` of length m is mapped to n cores locally on my machine, where n could be larger or smaller than m.  Each generator should run on a separate core.

If this is possible, can someone provide a minimal example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing with generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078980/python-multiprocessing-with-generator)

Comment: It could be on the right track, but I am looking for a minimal solution.  There are at least a few factors there - file i/o and examples that don't run - that prevent it, IMO, from being a truly easy-to-use and digestible Q&A.

Comment: `but I am looking for a minimal solution`, great but that would require a minimal reproducible example from your side as well :). Maybe give an example of the `complicated function that returns the next value of a complicated procedure`

Comment: What exactly are your complicated procedures? Are they computation heavy (e.g. solving physics equation), doing a lot of read/write to disk, networking operations?)

Comment: Computation heavy, but no file I/O or networking.

Comment: @PaulBrennan That question only uses a generator to produce *inputs*; the MP worker processes are themselves not generator-based.

Comment: You can’t do this **in general**. For *specific* cases where you can replace the generator by a more general iterator implementation that can cheaply be fast forwarded or where you can jump to a later iteration state directly, or you can pickle the current state of the iterator, you can delegate work to MP worker processes because you longer have to serialise generators.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pickle generators. Read more about it [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue1092962).

There is a blog post which explains it in much more detail. Referring a quote from it:

> Let’s ignore that problem for a moment and look what we would need to do to pickle a generator. Since a generator is essentially a souped-up function, we would need to save its bytecode, which is not guarantee to be backward-compatible between Python’s versions, and its frame, which holds the state of the generator such as local variables, closures and the instruction pointer. And this latter is rather cumbersome to accomplish, since it basically requires to make the whole interpreter picklable. So, any support for pickling generators would require a large number of changes to CPython’s core.

> Now if an object unsupported by pickle (e.g., a file handle, a socket, a database connection, etc) occurs in the local variables of a generator, then that generator could not be pickled automatically, regardless of any pickle support for generators we might implement. So in that case, you would still need to provide custom **getstate** and **setstate** methods. This problem renders any pickling support for generators rather limited.

He also suggests a solution, to use simple iterators.

> the best solution to this problem to the rewrite the generators as simple iterators (i.e., one with a `__next__` method). Iterators are easy and efficient space-wise to pickle because their state is explicit. You would still need to handle objects representing some external state explicitly however; you cannot get around this.

Another offered [solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112050840/http://metaoptimize.com/blog/2009/12/22/why-cant-you-pickle-generators-in-python-workaround-pattern-for-saving-training-state/) (which I haven't tried) suggests this

1. Con­vert the gen­er­a­tor to a class in which the gen­er­a­tor code is the `__iter__` method
2. Add `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` meth­ods to the class, to han­dling pick­ling. Remem­ber that you can’t pickle file objects. So `__setstate__` will have to re-open files, as necessary.

Comment: The `__iter__` method still can’t be a generator. A generator is an iterator that keeps state in a (paused) function. You *can* just implement an iterator without using generators (by implementing `__next__`).

Answer (score 0):

If your subtasks are truly parallel (do not rely on any shared state), you can do this with `multiprocesing.Pool()`.

Take a look at
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

This requires you to make the arguments of pool.map() serializable. You can't pass in a generator to your worker, but you can achieve something similar by defining your generator inside the target function, and pass in initialization arguments to the multiprocessing library:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker(value):
    # The generator is defined inside the multiprocessed function
    def gen():
        for k in range(value):
            time.sleep(1) # Simulate long running task
            yield k

    # Execute the generator
    for x in gen():
        print(x)
        # Do something with x?
        pass


pool = mp.Pool()
pool.map(worker, [2, 5, 2])

pool.join() # Wait for all the work to be finished.
pool.close() # Clean up system resources
```

The output will be:

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
3
4
```

Note that this solution only really works if you build your generators, then use them only once, as their final state is lost at the end of the worker function.

Keep in mind that anytime you want to use multiprocessing, you have to use for serializable objects due to the limitations of inter-process communication; this can often prove limiting.

If your process is not CPU bound but instead I/O bound (disk access, network access, etc), you'll have a much easier time using threads.

Comment: Two quick notes:
1. There are two bugs in your code.  You need  pool.close() after the map, and then it's just pool.join() at the end.
2. This partially works, except there is no way to continue using the generator between calls.  The state of where it left off will be erased with each execution, thus sort of defeating the point of the generator.

Comment: 1. Good point with join & close, will update the answer.
2. I'm aware  that the state is lost, hence why I mentioned its only similar to passing the generators. THis solution would work for "use once" generators. I'll add another comment clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pickle the generator, just send an index of the generator to the processing pool.

```
M = len(gens)
N = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def proc(gen_idx):
    return [r for r in gens[gen_idx]()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(N) as p:
        for r in p.imap_unordered(proc, range(M)):
            print(r)
```

Note that I don't call/initialize the generator until within the processing function.

Using `imap_unordered` will allow you to process the results as each generator completes.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to implement, just dont block the threads sincronusly, just constantly loop thru the states and join them on complition. This template shuld be good enough to give an idea, `self.done` alwais needs to be set last on thread complition and las on thread reuse.

```
import threading as th
import random
import time

class Gen_thread(th.Thread):

    def is_done(self):
        return self.done

    def get_result(self):
        return self.work_result

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.g_id = kwargs['id']
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.args = args
        self.work_result = None
        self.done = False
        th.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # time.sleep(*self.args) to pass variables
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
        self.work_result = 'Thread {0} done'.format(self.g_id + 1)
        self.done = True

class Gens(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n_needed = 0
        self.n_done = 0
        self.n_loop = n

        self.workers_tmp = None
        self.workers = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n_needed == 0:
            for w in range(self.n_loop):
                self.workers.append(Gen_thread(id=w))
                self.workers[w].start()
                self.n_needed += 1

        while self.n_done != self.n_needed:
            for w in range(self.n_loop):
                if self.workers[w].is_done():
                    self.workers[w].join()
                    self.workers_tmp = self.workers[w].get_result()
                    self.workers.pop(w)
                    self.n_loop -= 1
                    self.n_done += 1
                    return self.workers_tmp

        raise StopIteration()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for gen in Gens(4):
        print(gen)
```