# C - How to setup an associative array of function pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, associative-array

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
myValueType function1(myParam){}

myValueType function2(myParam){}

myArray[CONSTANT_STATE1] = &function1;
myArray[CONSTANT_STATE2] = &function2;

myValue = (*myArray[CONSTANT_STATE1])(myParam);
```

When I compile, it throws an error that I've redeclared function1.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown is almost right.  The problem is in your function declarations:

```
myValueType function1(myParam){}

myValueType function2(myParam){}
```

These are old-style K&R non-prototyped declarations - the name of the parameter is `myParam`, and the type has not been specified.  Perhaps you meant this?

```
myValueType function1(myParamType myParam){}

myValueType function2(myParamType myParam){}
```

Expanding your code out to a minimal compilable example:

```
typedef int myValueType, myParamType;
enum { CONSTANT_STATE1, CONSTANT_STATE2 };

myValueType function1(myParamType myParam){}

myValueType function2(myParamType myParam){}

void f(myParamType myParam)
{
    myValueType myValue;
    myValueType (*myArray[2])(myParamType);

    myArray[CONSTANT_STATE1] = &function1;
    myArray[CONSTANT_STATE2] = &function2;

    myValue = (*myArray[CONSTANT_STATE1])(myParam);
}
```

Comment: LOL, and after getting everything working, my poor little chip ran out of memory. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c/4384446#4384446) from user [Vijay Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133520/vijay-mathew):

Section 6.6 of [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) presents a simple dictionary (hashtable) data structure. I don't think a useful dictionary implementation could get any simpler than this. For your convenience, I reproduce the code here.

```
struct nlist { /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next; /* next entry in chain */
    char *name; /* defined name */
    char *defn; /* replacement text */
};

#define HASHSIZE 101
static struct nlist *hashtab[HASHSIZE]; /* pointer table */

/* hash: form hash value for string s */
unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != ’\0’; s++)
      hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}

/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
struct nlist *lookup(char *s)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
          return np; /* found */
    return NULL; /* not found */
}

char *strdup(char *);
/* install: put (name, defn) in hashtab */
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
          return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    } else /* already there */
        free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
    if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
       return NULL;
    return np;
}

char *strdup(char *s) /* make a duplicate of s */
{
    char *p;
    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1); /* +1 for ’\0’ */
    if (p != NULL)
       strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}
```

Note that if the hashes of two strings collide, it may lead to an `O(n)` lookup time. You can reduce the likely hood of collisions by increasing the value of `HASHSIZE`. For a complete discussion of the data structure, please consult the book.

Comment: Thank you. I'm programming a microchip, so I'll need to boil this way down. Thank you for the example.