# How can I convert an array name to an array pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a list of arrays, each with its own descriptive name. 
How can I create a pointer to a particular array just using the name (ie string) of the array?

Comment: It's better to use code to explain yourself.

Comment: not clear what you are asking ... or do you just want the address of an array variable? This can be done with `&` as for any other variable.

Comment: Needing to do this in any programming language is a sure sign you've designed things horribly. Why do you have a variable name in a string?

Comment: Do the arrays all have the same type, or do they have different types?

Comment: All the same type of the same dimension. I will implement it as a struct containing a name string. It's at this point I wish I can done it in C++...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you mean and what you want, then you want something as Map, Dictionary etc. For example, look at this question: [Quick Way to Implement Dictionary in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The C programming language is somewhat of a "low-level" language. It doesn't natively have any introspection constructs.

The names you see/use are just labels that are converted to addresses by the compiler when building a static executable, so the running code has no way to look up things by variable name.