# How to get the same MAC address?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am using the following code to get the MAC address:

```
IP_ADAPTER_INFO adpInfo[16];
DWORD len = sizeof(adpInfo);
GetAdaptersInfo(adpInfo, &len );
printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", adpInfo[0].Address[0], adpInfo[0].Address[1], adpInfo[0].Address[2], adpInfo[0].Address[3], adpInfo[0].Address[4], adpInfo[0].Address[5]);
```

However, if the computer has many network adapters (for example: Ethernet and WiFi), then every time I call this code I get a different MAC address.

Is there a way to always get the same MAC address (for example: Ethernet).

Comment: I always get the same.

Comment: @addy2012 Sorry, I meant you could get another MAC address at some point, and not immediately.

Comment: At some point? How do you mean?

Comment: @addy2012 I once called it and got the MAC AF-BB... and then I called it a couple of days later and I got the MAC D1-AE...

Comment: It should normally return information about *all* the adapters (that are installed/enabled) on the machine. In the code above you're only displaying the first one though, so if the order changes, you'll see a different one. Of course, it's also possible (with some adapters) for the user to modify an adapter's MAC address.

Comment: There are several ways to query the NICs configured on your Windows system: including [GetAdaptersInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [gethostbyname()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), etc.  Unfortunately, there is no reliable way to be sure you'll get the same NICs in the same order.  SUGGESTION: Copy the NICs to a sorted list (or a [dictionary hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c)).

Comment: `gethostbyname()` does not return NIC info. And using it to return local IPs is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Since GetAdaptersInfo method includes almost as much information as *IPCONFIG /ALL* (including your DHCP server, Gateway, IP address list, subnet mask and WINS server) you can use that. It also enumerates all the NICs on your PC, even if they are not connected to valid networks (but the NICs do have to be "enabled" in Windows)

Sample, print all interfaces:

```
static void GetMACaddress(void)
{
  IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[16];

  DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);

  DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(AdapterInfo, &dwBufLen);

  assert(dwStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);

  PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;

  do {
    PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address);
    pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
  }
  while(pAdapterInfo);
}
```

You can save the *AdapterName*, then compare it in next calls to make sure the MAC of specified adapter is retrieved.

Look at here for *IP_ADAPTER_INFO* structure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Code from: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm

Answer (score 1):

I believe enumeration of the network adaptor information by the windows os depends on the priority of the network adaptors.
Priorities of network adapters can be viewed ,edited by traversing to

Open Network and Sharing Centre -> Change adapter settings ->Advanced[Enable menu bar if not visible]->Advanced settings.
One can edit the priorities of the network adapter.
[image]