# How to get the address of a variable, if I have the name of the variable in string during runtime?

Tags: c

I'm expecting something like below.

```
int genVar001, genVar002, genVar003;
int adrgenVar, status;
char strvariable[] =  "genVar001";

status = somefunction(&strvariable, adrgenVar);
```

Where '*adrgenVar*' will have the address of genVar001.! If the variable is not available the status should return error.

Why it is required: for manipulation of the values in the runtime (via keyboard or files).

Lookup table will not help me because it would increase the job; maintain the table if anything new is added.

**Edit:**
I'm working with PLCs, [Here](https://code.google.com/p/br-standard/source/browse/trunk/NumAffaire/Logical/Libraries/sys_lib/sys_lib.fun) is the library which will allow me to do so. 
Function: PV_xgetadr.

Comment: See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c) for some answers on how to implement a dictionary in C. In case you don't know, dictionaries generally have a list of keys with associated values. I find it quite ideal for modifying variables using a string identifier during runtime.

Comment: C doesn't have any built-in introspection functions like this. There's no way to find a variable from its name.

Comment: Do you know an `int` is not guranteed to be able to hold an _address_?

Comment: @Barmar: Well, one certainly could write code which parses the symbol table (presuming it has not been stripped) and find the variable somehow. But you can also shoot your foot right before a marathon.

Comment: Nothing in the C language allows that. You will have to resort to platform-specific code.

Comment: If you want a standard way, you need to bite the bullet, and accept the need to "increase the job" and then maintain the table.  The only solution is to implement a lookup table.     Even if you are willing to accept a non-standard way, accessing debugging information in executables (apart from being system specific) is not for the faint hearted or lazy.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have any sort of introspection capabilities in the standard, there's no way to do what you're aiming for in a portable manner. And the non-portable manners (like using the executable's debug info or symbol table) would be a terrible idea.

But that doesn't mean there's no solution. Judging by your variable names, what you should be doing is:

```
int genVar[3];
```

Then you can dynamically index into that array at runtime. If that's not flexible enough, use a linked list or a hash map - there are quite a few implementations of those for C available (none in the standard though).