# How do I remove duplicate values in an array of structs C

Tags: c, struct

I have an array of structs where they are sorted by ID and there are duplicate entries of that ID within the array. Each struct in the array has a number of points assosiated with it and I want to find the total number of points for each ID. I want to remove any duplicates and store their total points value in a single struct reducing the size of my array.

```
typedef struct boat_data {
    int ID;
    int time_to_complete_race; //This can be ignored
    int points;
} boat_node;
typedef boat_node boat_ptr;
```

The current code that I have made doesn't seem to work as intended. `tot_boats` is the number of boats and `tot_members` is the number of members that have been found (by this I mean the number of non-duplicate ID's present). I have two array structs where the `final_boat_scores` is of the size of the number of members present and I want to store the `ID` value and the `points` value

```
for(int boat = 0; boat < (total_boats - tot_members); boat++) {
        for (int next_boat = 0; next_boat < (total_boats - tot_members); next_boat++) {
            if (boat_scores[boat].ID == boat_scores[next_boat].ID) {
                final_boat_scores[boat].ID = boat_scores[next_boat].ID;
                final_boat_scores[boat].points += boat_scores[next_boat].points;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are doing. If you want to "remove" an element from the array you need to move all the elements past it left one. So to remove `3` from `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` you move `4,5,6` to the left and it becomes `[1,2,4,5,6,6]`. Notice the extra `6`. Is this what you are trying to do? Are you allocating the array with `malloc`?

Comment: The `id` is a pretty good sign that one should use a hash set and avoid storing duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @Neil Could you link to an article on how to implement this in C?

Comment: It's orthogonal to the answer @stanle posted, and it took too much space, so I think that probably deserves an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please let me know if you can change the array input. If yes, can't you just check ID every time you need to store a new element into the array? If ID matches with already stored element, simply let recordedPoint += point (that is, add the point to be stored directly into the total point recorded on the array). This way you won't create duplicate entries.

EDIT: since you can't change the input array, you can loop through the `boat_score` array and the `final_boat_score` array and check if the ID of the current boat have been recorded to the `final_boat_score` array yet. If yes, then simply add it to the total score. I think the problem with your code is that you didn't loop through all the elements in your array, since your array size is definitely not `total_boats - tot_members`. You also don't need that `final_boat_scores[boat].ID = boat_scores[next_boat].ID;` line since it's redundant, your if statement only execute if that's true anyways.
your `break;` statement also prematurely ends your loop, in this case you can't break out of the loop early because you don't really know how many entries you have with same ID, right?

```
//remember to initialize final_boat_score first with all IDs you have
for (int i = 0; i < final_boat_score_size; i++) {
    //initialize the total point = 0 first
    final_boat_score[i].points = 0;
    //then loop through your input data
    for (int j = 0; j < boat_score_size; i++) {
        //if there exist an input element boat_score[j] with the same ID
        //as the current final_boat_score[i] element, add its points to the total
        if (final_boat_score[i].ID == boat_score[j].ID) {
            final_boat_score[i].points += boat_score[j].points;
        }
    }
}
```

This won't delete the original array though so you will needs to delete it yourself if you don't need it anymore. I hope this help!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please turn it into a comment.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie he cant.

Comment: No I sadly can't change the in input

Comment: @stanle this is great but I'm not sure how to add all my ID's into the ```final_boat_score[]``` as they are stored in another struct

Comment: No worries I've figured out how to do it thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

More and more data renders the sorting-and-removing duplicates increasingly unfeasible, (though this may take a while.) One is describing a **set** with equality determined by `id`. It is a very common data structure; for example, in [relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), the `id` would be your key. Instead of de-duplicating every time, the set does not allow duplicates in the first place. A [common implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Implementations) is a hash set implemented as a hash map from the keys, (in this case, `ID`,) to a sentinel value that indicates the presence of the key, (any `char` or `int` will do.) A [static set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Static_sets) has a very good `C` implementation in [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/), which creates a minimal perfect hash, but I believe you want to have dynamic content, (which would translate to allowing other competitors to join the club.)

Since one key is a number, it's fairly easy to create a hash function from the projection,

```
int hash(const struct boat_data *const b) {
    return b->ID;
}
```

A lot of languages have support for hash maps in their standard library, (for example, [JavaScript version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array/9229821#9229821) of your question,) but C does not. However, one will find a lot of implementations. See a [Quick Way to Implement Dictionary in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c). Also, [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html), [Android](https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils/hashmap.c) (uses `void *`key,) [Git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/hashmap.c), [statsd hashmap](https://github.com/statsite/statsite/blob/master/src/hashmap.c) (uses strings,) [GHash](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html), [HMap](http://www.koanlogic.com/libu/api/html/group__hmap.html).

If the `ID` is bounded, (and within the range of computability,) it's simple to create a (not minimal) [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) function.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */

static unsigned points_by_id[1000];
static size_t id_size = sizeof points_by_id / sizeof *points_by_id;

int main(void) {
    size_t i;
    /* First race between [45 36, 10]. */
    points_by_id[45] += 45;
    points_by_id[36] += 20;
    points_by_id[10] += 100;
    /* Second race between [10, 12, 45] */
    points_by_id[10] += 31;
    points_by_id[12] += 40;
    points_by_id[45] += 30;
    /* Print out. */
    printf("Total stadings:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < id_size; i++) {
        if(points_by_id[i])
            printf("%lu\t%u\n", (unsigned long)i, points_by_id[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```