# Small Lookup Table for Large Integers

Tags: c, performance, lookup-tables

I want to make a quick, relatively small lookup table, but with a large input range:
-Input: 32bit Value max. (a 32bit color value)
-Output: 8bit Index max. (index to a table)

Something like the code below. (If more than 256 values are indexed, the index is just going to be 0)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint8_t getIndx(uint32_t value);
static uint8_t **indx;
static uint8_t count = 0;

int main(void) {
  // set up the indx
  const uint32_t size = 0xFFFF;  // for demonstrative purposes not even nearly as large as wished to be (0xFFFFFFFF) plus my for loop below would get in trouble, I think
  indx = (uint8_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t*) * size);
  if(indx == NULL) {
    printf("could not allocate memory\n");
    return 0;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
    indx[i] = NULL;
  }

  printf("%d\n", getIndx(111));
  printf("%d\n", getIndx(222));
  printf("%d\n", getIndx(333));
  printf("%d\n", getIndx(111));
  printf("%d\n", getIndx(222));
  printf("%d\n", getIndx(333));

  return 0;
}

static uint8_t getIndx(uint32_t value) {
  if(indx[value] == NULL) {
    if(count > 255) return 0;
    indx[value] = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
    *indx[value] = count;
    count++;
  }
  return *(indx[value]);
}
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

No matter what I think of, I always end up with something like that. With an input range of 32bit (4294967296 states) I would need to allocate way too much memory to only get 256 possible outputs. And forming 256 `if else`, inside a `for` loop or not, is also not what I want.

Is there some method that is quick, either a table or not which in the end has the same function, that I have not yet heard about?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for "hash table". Have you looked into whether that does what you need? There are various variants of the hash table depending on what kind of memory vs performance tradeoff point suits your needs.

Comment: Googling "c dictionary" takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c).

Comment: Note that `if(count > 255)` will never be true as `count` is of type `uint8_t`. Is it correct to say that the maximum number of element in the table will be 256? Which kind of hardware do you target?

Comment: What are you asking for? A solution that does not use as much memory? And you want a function that remembers its first 256 inputs and returns their assigned numbers when it sees those inputs again and zeros for other inputs?

Comment: FYI, you allocate space for `size` elements but initialize `size+1` elements.

Comment: Argh! I messed up the count... Well, you guys noticed before me. And yes thanks for asking @JérômeRichard, I target Computers. ErocProstpischil no and yes, I need an approach. Somethink like HansPassant sent, I will look into that.

Comment: I wonder if "32-bit color value" is actually four separate 8-bit pieces packed together (e.g. "RGBA") that should be unpacked with shifts/masks before using each piece separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hash table to map the 32-bit values to the look-up table indices. The length of the hash table should be significantly longer than the look-up table to reduce the chance of hash collisions.

The following example uses a linear search of the hash table starting at the hash value derived from the input value until a matching entry is found or an empty hash table is found. If the input value is not found, and there is room in the look-up table and room in the hash table (which there should be since it is longer than the look-up table), the input value is added to the look-up table and the hash table is updated.  It uses a hash table four times the size of the look-up table.

The example does two passes with the same pseudo-random sequence in each pass.  The first pass should mostly fill up the look-up table and update the hash table. The second pass shouldn't make any more changes to the look-up table or hash table because it is just repeating the first sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

struct hash_index {
  uint8_t index;
  char used;
};

#define HASHBITS  10
#define HASHSIZE  (1U << HASHBITS)
#define HASHMASK  (HASHSIZE - 1)
#define LOOKUPSIZE  256U

static uint8_t getIndx(uint32_t value);
static uint32_t lookup[LOOKUPSIZE];
static struct hash_index hashtab[HASHSIZE];
static unsigned int count = 0;
static unsigned int tot_collisions = 0;
static unsigned int max_collisions = 0;
static unsigned int hash_used = 0;

int main(void) {
  int pass;
  unsigned int i;
  uint32_t value;
  uint8_t index;
  unsigned int successes;
  unsigned int failures;
  int ok;

  printf("Lookup size: %u, Hash size: %u\n", LOOKUPSIZE, HASHSIZE);
  for (pass = 1; pass <= 2; pass++) {
    successes = 0;
    failures = 0;
    tot_collisions = 0;
    max_collisions = 0;
    /* Not resetting hash_used because it shouldn't change after first pass. */
    printf("\nPass %d, currently used hashes: %u\n\n", pass, hash_used);
    srand(1);
    for (i = 0; i < 260; i++) {
      static const char * const outcomes[2] = {"FAIL", "OK"};
      value = rand();
      index = getIndx(value);
      ok = lookup[index] == value;
      printf("%" PRIu32 " -> %" PRIu8 " (%s)\n", value, index, outcomes[ok]);
      if (ok) {
        successes++;
      } else {
        failures++;
      }
    }
    printf("\nSuccesses: %u, Failures: %u\n", successes, failures);
    printf("Used hashes: %u, Total collisions: %u, Max collisions: %u\n\n",
           hash_used, tot_collisions, max_collisions);
  }

  return 0;
}

static uint8_t getIndx(uint32_t value) {
  unsigned int initial_hash;
  unsigned int hash;
  unsigned int collisions = 0;
  uint8_t index;

  /*
   * Search for value using hash table, starting at position hashed from value.
   *
   * The hash table is longer than the maximum number of used entries,
   * so we should always be able to find an unused entry in the hash table.
   */
  initial_hash = ((value * UINT32_C(0x61c88647)) >> (32 - HASHBITS)) & HASHMASK;
  for (hash = initial_hash;
       collisions < HASHSIZE && hashtab[hash].used;
       hash = (hash + 1) & HASHMASK) {
    /*
     * This hash table entry is used.  Get the corresponding index in the
     * main lookup table to check if the value matches.
     */
    index = hashtab[hash].index;
    if (lookup[index] == value) {
      /* Matching value found.  Return its index in the main table. */
      return index;
    }
    /* Count hash collisions and total hash collisions. */
    collisions++;
    tot_collisions++;
    if (max_collisions < collisions) {
      /* Update max hash collisions for diagnostics. */
      max_collisions = collisions;
    }
  }
  /* Value not found. */
  if (count < LOOKUPSIZE && collisions < HASHSIZE) {
    /*
     * There is room in the main lookup table for the new value
     * and room in the hash table.  The index of the new value in the
     * main lookup table will be the current count, which will be incremented.
     */
    index = count++;
    /*
     * Add value to main lookup table,
     * add index in main lookup table to hash table,
     * and return the index in the main lookup table.
     */
    lookup[index] = value;
    hashtab[hash].index = index;
    hashtab[hash].used = 1;
    hash_used++;  /* Count of used hash table entries for diagnostics. */
    return index;
  }
  /*
   * Value not found and main lookup table is full or hash table is full.
   * Give up.
   */
  return 0;
}
```

Another approach for dealing with collisions is to make each hash table entry point to a linked list of matching values, but that is more complicated.

Comment: This looks promising. Where did you learn about hashing? Can you recommend a book, a website or anything else? Because I don't know anything about it...