# Segfault in C while Implementing a Simple Dictionary

Tags: c, dictionary, segmentation-fault

So I tried implementing a simple dictionary as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384359/quick-way-to-implement-dictionary-in-c). However, I did modify the code:

a) The dictionary:

```
/* String utility for duplication */
char *strdup(char *s) /* make a duplicate of s */
{
    char *p;
    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1); /* +1 for ’\0’ */
    if (p != NULL)
       strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}

struct nlist {
    struct nlist *next;
    char *name;
    char *defn;
};

#define HASHSIZE 101
struct Dict {
    struct nlist *hashtab[HASHSIZE];
};

/* hash: form hash value for string s */
unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
      hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}

/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
struct nlist *lookup(struct Dict *d, char *s)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    for (np = d->hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
          return np; /* found */
    return NULL; /* not found */
}

struct nlist *insert(struct Dict *d, char *name, char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(d, name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
          return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = d->hashtab[hashval];
        d->hashtab[hashval] = np;
    } else /* already there */
        free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
    if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
       return NULL;
    return np;
}
```

b) Example:

```
int main() {
    struct Dict *dtest = (struct Dict*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dict));
    insert(dtest, "hello", "world");
    // Look up a definition by name
    struct nlist *result = lookup(dtest, "hello");
    
    if (result != NULL) {
        printf("Definition for 'hello': %s\n", result->defn);
    } else {
        printf("'hello' is not found in the dictionary.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I tried debugging it, I received this error:

> Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007ff6bc661626 in lookup (d=0x220924616e0, s=0x7ff6bc673006 "hello") at dict.c:40
> 40              if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)

I just don't understand how a simple modification of the code could produce this unexpected behavior, and quite frankly, not sure how to go about it.

Comment: If you've got a fault in the debugger, look very carefully at the variables involved. Since `s` seems valid, are you sure `np->name` is? Did `hash(s)` produce a value outside the bounds of your allocation? Normally the hash is modulo hash-size which is dynamic, and you have it status here, but still, that should be fine. You may want to inspect what `hash(s)` is, as well as what `np` and `np->name` are.

Comment: I am not sure, but the original code did not pose this problem. That is why I am confused.

Comment: It doesn't look like dtest is properly initialized.  I doubt that it's internal data is consistent.

Comment: This might be a case where `calloc()`, which zeroes out memory, creates defined behaviour. If your compiler fills allocated memory with trash on purpose to shake out bugs, you may end up with a crash. This is where a proper allocation function comes in handy, like `create_dict()` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code snippet, the `hashtab` array is declared as `static`, which means its elements are automatically initialized to `NULL` at the program start. This is a key difference from dynamically allocated memory (like with `malloc`), where the contents are uninitialized.

When you declare a `static` array of pointers like `static struct nlist *hashtab[HASHSIZE];`, all the pointers in this array are initialized to `NULL` by default. This initialization is done by the system when the program starts, before any function is called. This is part of the C language standard, which specifies that objects with static storage duration are initialized to zero (or `NULL` for pointers) if no explicit initializer is provided.

Therefore, the `hashtab` array starts with all its elements set to `NULL`, and there is no need for additional initialization code for this array.

In the previous code snippet you provided, the situation is different:

```c
struct Dict {
    struct nlist *hashtab[HASHSIZE];
};
```

In your code, `hashtab` is a member of a struct, and it is not declared as `static`. When you dynamically allocate memory for this struct using `malloc`, as in:

```c
struct Dict *dtest = (struct Dict*)malloc(sizeof(struct Dict));
```

the `hashtab` array within `dtest` is not automatically initialized. The `malloc` function allocates memory without initializing it, so the contents of the allocated memory are indeterminate. In the case of `hashtab`, this means its pointers could point to any arbitrary memory location.

Thus, for this struct, you must explicitly initialize the `hashtab` array to ensure that each pointer in the array is set to `NULL` before you use them. Failure to do so can lead to undefined behavior, such as segmentation faults when you try to access or modify the data through these uninitialized pointers.

The initialization can be done like this:

```c
// Initialize the hash table
for (int i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++) {
    dtest->hashtab[i] = NULL;
}
```

This loop sets each pointer in the `hashtab` array to `NULL`, ensuring that they are properly initialized before use.