Mapping an array to a name in C
Unsure how to phrase this, but I'll give it a try
I have a set of arrays that I have defined like this, they are C style images.
static uint8_t wsymbol_0043_mostly_cloudy[] PROGMEM  = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

And a set of names for collection of C style images in an array like this
 String* symbols[] = {
"wsymbol_0001_sunny",
"wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals",
"wsymbol_0003_white_cloud"};

Now using C I want to be able to map the symbols array here to the sets of C style images? But I don't know how I can do so in C.
I need to pass the array wsymbol_0001_sunny[] to a method, not the name wsymbol_0001_sunny?
Is the answer the "map" function in C?

These should probably be const so they get declared in flash, not RAM.

The common way to do it is by an array of structures
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

static uint8_t wsymbol_0043_mostly_cloudy[] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

static uint8_t wsymbol_0043_mostly_sunny[] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

struct named_array {
   char *name;
   uint8_t *array;
};

struct named_array data[] = {
   { "wsymbol_0001_sunny", wsymbol_0043_mostly_sunny },
   { "wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals", wsymbol_0043_mostly_cloudy },
   { NULL, NULL }
};

uint8_t * find_array(const char *name) {
   int idx=0;
   while(data[idx].name) {
      if (strcmp(data[idx].name, name) == 0) return data[idx].array;
      idx++;
   }
   return NULL;
}


That's one perfectly reasonable way to do it, but calling it the common way implies more than I think you can support.

It would be more common (hopefully) to constify everything that is supposed to be immutable.

The most straight-forward way is to declare two arrays where the indices correspond. For example if you have String* symbols[n] = { "sunny", ... and some image table of pointers pointing at arrays
static uint8_t* images[n] = { wsymbol_0001_sunny, ... then index 0 ties them together.
Then you could even create an enum to named the shared constants:
typedef enum
{
  WEATHER_SUNNY,
  ...
} weather_index_t;


Another solution is to allocate everything together in structs, then make an array of struct objects. This makes the grouping more intuitive, at the expense of ever so slightly slower access.

An advanced version of the array example is to generate the whole lot through X-macros. They are pretty ideal for this kind of setup, where you have similarly named data in various forms.
X macros make the code quite a bit harder to read, but much easier to maintain. You get rid of code repetition and you get a flexible format ideal for compile-time generation/data flash storage. And with the aid of an enum and designated initializers, you can add coupling and automatic sanity checks to ensure data integrity between the various arrays.
For example:
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define WEATHER_LIST(X)    \
/*  str              n */  \
  X(sunny,           0001) \
  X(sunny_intervals, 0002) \
  X(white_cloud,     0003) \

typedef enum
{
  #define WEATHER_ENUM(str, n) str,
  WEATHER_LIST(WEATHER_ENUM)

  WEATHERS_N // total amount of items in the X-macro list
} weather_index_t;

static const char* const weather_str[] =
{
  #define WEATHER_STR(str, n) [str] = "wsymbol_" #n "_" #str,
  WEATHER_LIST(WEATHER_STR)
};
static_assert(sizeof weather_str/sizeof *weather_str == WEATHERS_N,
              "weather_str data size inconsitency vs weather_index_t");

static const uint8_t weather_image[][3] = 
{
  [sunny]           = {1,2,3},
  [sunny_intervals] = {4,5,6},
  [white_cloud]     = {7,8,9}
};
static_assert(sizeof weather_image/sizeof *weather_image == WEATHERS_N,
              "weather_image data size inconsitency vs weather_index_t");

int main()
{
  puts(weather_str[sunny]);
  for(size_t i=0; i<WEATHERS_N; i++)
    printf("%"PRIu8 " ", weather_image[sunny][i]);
}

Output:
wsymbol_0001_sunny
1 2 3 


There is no support for dictionaries in C, so you'll have to either implement a dictionary yourself or borrow someone else's implementation.
Since the names of the image already have an identifier, you can put the raw image data in an nested array like this:
static uint8_t image_data[][] PROGMEM = {
    {/* wsymbol_0001_sunny */}, 
    {/* wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals */}, 
    {/* ... */}
}
char *symbols[] = {
    "wsymbol_0001_sunny",
    "wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals",
    "wsymbol_0003_white_cloud"
};

Then you can access an image by its name like this:
image_data[atoi(symbols[1]+8)-1];

This will break if the number in the name of the image is not the correct index of the image data. If you want a proper dictionary then you can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4384446

Since everything is available at compile-time, there's really no need to do a run-time look-up. (Also atoi is dangerous since it has poor error handling and strtol is always to prefer.)

You cannot define uint8_t image_data[][] like that. You need to define the length for all but the leftmost dimension.

I'm almost tempted not to share this solution, because the best way is to use a struct as mentioned by @White Owl.
If, for whatever reason, you do not want to use a struct to mimic a map, and want to keep the arrays separate yet have a well-defined matching of the images and names, you can use MACROS and XMACROS.
This is more of a fun fact rather than a viable solution.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint8_t wsymbol_0001_sunny[]            = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
static uint8_t wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals[]  = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
static uint8_t wsymbol_0003_white_cloud[]      = { 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };

#define SYMBOL(N) N

#define SET_SYMBOLS                       \
    SYMBOL(wsymbol_0001_sunny),           \
    SYMBOL(wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals), \
    SYMBOL(wsymbol_0003_white_cloud)        

static uint8_t* symbol_images[] = { SET_SYMBOLS };

#undef SYMBOL
#define SYMBOL(N) #N

const char* symbol_names[] = { SET_SYMBOLS };

int main(void)
{
    int elem = 1;
    printf("img: %03x is called: %s\n",symbol_images[elem][0], symbol_names[elem] );
}

Online example: https://rextester.com/QHPX44645
In this example, the order you define the arrays in the SET_SYMBOLS macro will also determine the order the names are laid out in the array of names.

In C it is possible to create maps using lookup tables.

Here a example:
#include <stdio.h>

static int parse_numbers[] = {
    ['1'] = 'A',
    ['2'] = 'B',
    ['3'] = 'C'
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%c\n", parse_numbers['1']);
    printf("%c\n", parse_numbers['2']);
    printf("%c\n", parse_numbers['3']);

    return 0;
}

These are powerful to obtain exactly what you asked for. It works thanks enums.

In fact, the following syntax produces the same result (discouraged!):
#include <stdio.h>

enum numbers {
    number_1 = 1,
    number_2 = 2,
    number_3 = 3,
};

static int parse_numbers[] = {
    [number_1] = 'A',
    [number_2] = 'B',
    [number_3] = 'C'
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%c\n", parse_numbers['1']);
    printf("%c\n", parse_numbers['2']);
    printf("%c\n", parse_numbers['3']);

    return 0;
}

This syntax is very reluctant from changes. It is easy to make mistakes changing the enum or the struct. Please, stay away from this, use the first one.

I sorry to say, although his looks like a great approach my Arduino environment sadly chokes on it..sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported. It chokes on both versions, even the one I needed to avoid.

@user3069232 I understand, no problem! Maybe consider to specify that you are working on arduino in your question, so that people can obtain more details about your issue.

Thanks to everyone who answered. I ended up doing like this... I figured the images are hardcoded, so I just hard code identifying which one to display to in a case statement.
switch(wsymbol) {
    case 1: tft.pushImage(ximage + jmp, yimage + twk, 64, 64, wsymbol_0001_sunny);break;
    case 2: tft.pushImage(ximage + jmp, yimage + twk, 64, 64, wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals);break;
    case 3: tft.pushImage(ximage + jmp, yimage + twk, 64, 64, wsymbol_0003_white_cloud);break;
    case 6: tft.pushImage(ximage + jmp, yimage + twk, 64, 64, wsymbol_0006_mist);break;

    default: tft.pushImage(ximage + jmp, yimage + twk, 64, 64, wsymbol_0999_unknown);
  }
}

